# @font-face fonts doesn't render consistently on all Android versions

Tags: android, css, html, cordova, fonts

I'm trying to use a customized Roboto font for Arabic but fail to get it rendered properly in a PhoneGap/Android application:

- On Galaxy ACE (Android 2.3.2), my application renders properly Arabic characters (see image#1).
- On Galaxy S3 and S4 (Android 4.3), my application renders Arabic characters using the default font (see image#2).

**Image#1**

[image]

**Image#2**

[image]

**html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ArabicFont';
        src: url("fonts/KacstTitle.ttf") format("truetype");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'LatinFont';
        src: url("fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf") format("truetype");
    }

    .arabicText {
        font-family: ArabicFont;
        direction: rtl;
    }
    .latinText {
        font-family: LatinFont;
        direction: ltr;
    }
    .center {
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="libreOfficeRendering" class="center">
            <hr/>
            <label>LibreOffice Rendering</label>
            <hr/>
            <img src="images/libreOfficeRendering.png">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div id="googleChromeRendering" class="center">
            <hr/>
            <label>Google-Chrome Rendering</label>
            <hr/>
            <img src="images/googleChromeRendering.png">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div id="androidAndPhoneGabRendering" class="center">
            <hr/>
            <label>Actual Rendering</label>
            <hr/>
            <pre class="arabicText">أنا نص بحروف عربية (KacstTitle).</pre>
            <pre class="latinText">I'm a text in Latin characters (DejaVu Serif).</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: arabic and persian fonts not working in android verssion <= 4.3 using font face. also samsung has own stock arabic / persian font which is pretty ugly

Answer (score 0):

Try testing something like this to see if it is possibly an issue with `<pre>` tags and/or `html`:

```
<span class="arabicText">&#x623;&#x646;&#x627; &#x646;&#x635; &#x628;&#x62D;&#x631;&#x648;&#x641; &#x639;&#x631;&#x628;&#x64A;&#x629;</span>

<pre class="arabicText">&#x623;&#x646;&#x627; &#x646;&#x635; &#x628;&#x62D;&#x631;&#x648;&#x641; &#x639;&#x631;&#x628;&#x64A;&#x629;</pre>

<span class="arabicText">أنا نص بحروف عربية</span>

<pre class="arabicText">أنا نص بحروف عربية</pre>
```

If any of those render correctly on the device in question maybe it can help narrow down the issue.

Another possibility is a strange thing I encountered recently where in certain browsers (seemingly at random), fonts defined by `@font-face` would not render unless I formatted the `font-family` name *exactly the same **including punctuation*** when using it later.  So you could try wrapping the `font-family` in quotes in all instances:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArabicFont'; /* has quotes */
    src: url("fonts/KacstTitle.ttf") format("truetype");
}
.arabicText {
    font-family: 'ArabicFont'; /* has quotes */
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Or removing quotes in all instances:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ArabicFont; /* no quotes */
    src: url("fonts/KacstTitle.ttf") format("truetype");
}
.arabicText {
    font-family: ArabicFont; /* no quotes */
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Hopefully one of those will help you out.  Last thought - is there possibly a capitalization difference in the file name between what you are referencing and how it's actually saved?